# plotly inside jupyter notebook python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

Does anyone know how to use `plotly` inside `jupyter notebook` using python?

The documentation is not very well organized, at-least not from my point of view.

For example, I can run the following code but it generates a graph in a HTML file that can be accessed OUTSIDE of `jupyter notebook`. Is there a way for the graph to be rendered inside the notebook?

What is also not clear to me (as documentation is poor) is that does one require a credentials to use `plotly` for plots inside `jupyter notebook`? Are the credentials only required for hosting the plots on their cloud and nothing more?

As well I find that there isn't any real documentation of `cufflinks`. All it says is it makes using `plotly` with `pandas` dataframes easier. But for someone who isn't a developer it would be nice if there was detailed documentation on why exactly is it necessary and what exactly is it doing that makes life easier.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

trace0 = Scatter(
  x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
  y=[10, 15, 13, 17]
)
trace1 = Scatter(
  x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
  y=[16, 5, 11, 9]
)
data = Data([trace0, trace1])

plotly.offline.plot(data, filename = 'basic-line')

/Users/blahblah/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/offline/offline.py:433: UserWarning:

Your filename `basic-line` didn't end with .html. Adding .html to the end of your file.

'file:///Users/blahblach/Box Sync/NS/NBooks/basic-line.html'
In [ ]:
```

If I change the last line in the code to:

```
py.iplot(data, filename = 'basic-line')
```

I get the credential error:

```
PlotlyLocalCredentialsError: 
Couldn't find a 'username', 'api-key' pair for you on your local machine. To sign in temporarily (until you stop running Python), run:
>>> import plotly.plotly as py
>>> py.sign_in('username', 'api_key')

Even better, save your credentials permanently using the 'tools' module:
>>> import plotly.tools as tls
>>> tls.set_credentials_file(username='username', api_key='api-key')

For more help, see https://plot.ly/python.
```

UPDATE:

I tried to execute the pandas examples as described [here](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/).

I get credential errors for all `df.iplot()` or `Series.iplot()` commands.

Can someone kindly explain why am I getting credential errors despite using iplot().

There is also no useful documentation regarding `cufflinks`.

The `plot.ly` documentation is one of the worst I have seen. Organization is a mess and not very example friendly.

Comment: I was able to plot fig in jupyter by importing `from IPython.display import display` and using as `display(fig)`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/offline/), you need to initiate the Plotly Notebook with `init_notebook_mode`, also note that when you call `py.iplot` it is still calling the plot function from online plotly module, you need to import the **iplot**(not plot) from `plotly.offline` and use it for offline plot and inside notebook rendering. You don't need the credentials for offline plot:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)         # initiate notebook for offline plot

trace0 = Scatter(
  x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
  y=[10, 15, 13, 17]
)
trace1 = Scatter(
  x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
  y=[16, 5, 11, 9]
)

iplot([trace0, trace1])               # use plotly.offline.iplot for offline plot
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to execute something like this df.iplot(kind='scatter',...) offline? No useable documentation on cufflinks exists. I get credential errors when I try the cufflinks example above from https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/

Comment: Yes, you can go offline with `import cufflinks as cf
; cf.go_offline()` command. Then `df.iplot(kind='scatter', filename='cufflinks/cf-simple-line')` should render the plot inside the notebook.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me. I am using Anaconda, the plot is not embebed in Jupiter but generated outside, anyhow it works.

```
import plotly.offline as py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

xl = pd.ExcelFile('c:\\Users\\xxx\Downloads\\krko.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("All_Kr") 
krw=df.get_values()[:,12] # Column 13
kro=df.get_values()[:,11] # Column 12
Sw=df.get_values()[:,5]   # Column 6

Sw_vs_krw=go.Scatter(x=Sw,y=krw,name='krw')
Sw_vs_kro=go.Scatter(x=Sw,y=kro,name='kro')
data = [Sw_vs_krw, Sw_vs_kro]
py.plot(data,layout,filename='C:\\Users\\earro\\basic-line-plot.html')
```

[Plotly resulst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co0jz.png)