# Show plotly plots in a auto-generated Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to generate a series of notebooks with `plotly` plots through a script. Problem is `plotly` plots don't show even after being executed. In the example below I the `matplotlib` plot shows up just fine, but for the `ploly` visualiztion to show up I have to re-run it manually.

Is there way to have the `plotly` plot be saved in the notebook so that it doesn't need to be re-run?

```py
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
import nbformat as nbf

nb = nbf.v4.new_notebook()

# Make a few visualizations
code = """\
%pylab inline
hist(normal(size=2000), bins=50);"""

code2 = """\
%pylab inline
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill")
fig.show()
"""

nb['cells'] = [
    nbf.v4.new_code_cell(code),
    nbf.v4.new_code_cell(code2),
]


# Execute the notebook
ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
ep.preprocess(nb)


with open('test.ipynb', 'w') as f:
    nbf.write(nb, f)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plotly inside jupyter notebook python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323423/plotly-inside-jupyter-notebook-python)

Comment: Looked promising for a second there but no, still disappears if I restart the kernel + close and re-open the notebook.

Comment: Can you tell if the output is getting saved? Are you setting `trust` on in your notebook? There's a command you can use to actually set it to trusted, an example is [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/a170e2201329624996b761a0d5213a196c32b896/postBuild#L3). I think you can usually test that will help by opening the notebook first and changing the test setting.

Comment: Yes its being saved. The exact same thing happens if you save it manually.
Once the kernel is killed and notebook is closed and re-opened, the plotly plots disappear while the matplotlib ones persist. It looks like a plotly config issue not a permission issue.