# Jupyter not showing visual representation

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, cluster-analysis

I am researching to make a visual representation of clusters, and I have found the following source: https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-point-clustering/#3d-clustering-with-alpha-shapes

In it you can find a code of a clustering that has been done and I wish to recreate the same in my Jupyter Notebook. However, I do not get any visual representation.

My code is as follows:

```
import plotly as py
!pip install plotly==3.10.0
from chart_studio import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd

jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/alpha_shape.csv')
df.head()

scatter = dict(
    mode = "markers",
    name = "y",
    type = "scatter3d",
    x = df['x'], y = df['y'], z = df['z'],
    marker = dict( size=2, color="rgb(23, 190, 207)" )
)
clusters = dict(
    alphahull = 7,
    name = "y",
    opacity = 0.1,
    type = "mesh3d",
    x = df['x'], y = df['y'], z = df['z']
)
layout = dict(
    title = '3d point clustering',
    scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict( zeroline=False ),
        yaxis = dict( zeroline=False ),
        zaxis = dict( zeroline=False ),
    )
)
fig = dict( data=[scatter, clusters], layout=layout )
# Use py.iplot() for IPython notebook
py.iplot(fig, filename='3d point clustering')
```

Does anyone know what error it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plotly inside jupyter notebook python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323423/plotly-inside-jupyter-notebook-python)

Comment: Hi @G.Anderson , I have tried it and did not work... copying exactly what is specified in the ansewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the core of the issue is that you're using an old version of plotly. Currently it's at [`5.9.0`](https://pypi.org/project/plotly/5.9.0/), but your code tries to install version 3.10.0 (`!pip install plotly==3.10.0`).

Since version 4, plotly is ["*is offline only, and does not include any functionality for uploading figures or data to cloud services*"](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#installation).
If you're using JupyterLab 3.0 or newer you don't need the `jupyterlab-plotly` extension either.

To make it work with the current version of plotly you can adjust your code as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
!pip install plotly
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/alpha_shape.csv")
df.head()

scatter = dict(
    mode="markers",
    name="y",
    type="scatter3d",
    x=df["x"],
    y=df["y"],
    z=df["z"],
    marker=dict(size=2, color="rgb(23, 190, 207)"),
)
clusters = dict(alphahull=7, name="y", opacity=0.1, type="mesh3d", x=df["x"], y=df["y"], z=df["z"])
layout = dict(
    title="3d point clustering",
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(zeroline=False),
        yaxis=dict(zeroline=False),
        zaxis=dict(zeroline=False),
    ),
)
fig = go.Figure(data=[scatter, clusters], layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it to display in Jupyter notebook. The error was due to plotly authenticiation error, so import iplot from offline.

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
iplot(fig, filename='3d point clustering')
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import iplot
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/alpha_shape.csv')
df.head()

scatter = dict(
    mode = "markers",
    name = "y",
    type = "scatter3d",
    x = df['x'], y = df['y'], z = df['z'],
    marker = dict( size=2, color="rgb(23, 190, 207)" )
)
clusters = dict(
    alphahull = 7,
    name = "y",
    opacity = 0.1,
    type = "mesh3d",
    x = df['x'], y = df['y'], z = df['z']
)
layout = dict(
    title = '3d point clustering',
    scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict( zeroline=False ),
        yaxis = dict( zeroline=False ),
        zaxis = dict( zeroline=False ),
    )
)
fig = dict( data=[scatter, clusters], layout=layout )
# Use py.iplot() for IPython notebook
iplot(fig, filename='3d point clustering')
```